# Install ubuntu goes blank hp envy m7 touchsmart

Tags: installation

When installing from the cd it gives the option to try ubuntu or install.  But when I select install the screen goes blank.

Comment: Might sound stupid, but try increasing screen brightness from the laptop keyboard. Screen brightness becoming 0 is a known issue that can happen during installation or boot.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076

Comment: It was the screen automatically dimming itself.  Thanks for the advice

Answer (score -1):

looks like your laptop came with locked bios 
have a look at this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: It's not locked.  I have no problem disabling Safe Boot.